# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth' not found

Tags: laravel

am getting error like Class 'App\Http\Controllers\admin\Auth' not found in laravel 5 while login. i am new to laravel so please help me or give me some tutorial link for complete laravel application development with admin side

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIVCU.png)

[admin login controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3zt3.png)

[route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9u1G.png)

[login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkqDk.png)

Comment: Namespace must be firstly. Change namespace position. It must be in line 2 then must be use `use` statement

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of your code. Attach relevant code in your question instead of adding screenshots

Comment: You are missing: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`at the top

Answer (score 0):

Use directly at the top of your Controller, after the namespace line

```
use Auth;
```

Comment: error is gone but it still logged in after post to @logout route

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `\Auth` instead `Auth`. 
`\Auth` give you access to `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` facade.